# Laravel pagination on each side not working properly

Tags: laravel, pagination

In my Laravel (5.7) controller, I have set pagination + 'on each side navigation' to 2 items. However, this is not working on my view. I'm getting much more items than 2, which causes my window to break out on small mobile devices.

What can be the cause of this and how can I fix it? I mean, I can get it fixed with CSS, but I would like to get it fixed the proper way.

My code in the controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $type = 'all';

    if ($request->has('type')) {
        if ($request->type == 'all') {
            $materials = Material::paginate(10)->onEachSide(2);
        } else {
            $type = $request->type;
            $materials = Material::where('type', $type)->paginate(10)->onEachSide(2);
        }
    } else {
        $materials = Material::paginate(10)->onEachSide(2);
    }

    
    $stock = array(
        'enkelzitKajaks' => Material::where('type', 'Enkelzitkajak')->count(),
        'dubbelzitKajaks' => Material::where('type', 'Dubbelzitkajak')->count(),
        'canadeseKanos' => Material::where('type', 'Canadese kano')->count(),
        'langePeddels' => Material::where('type', 'Lange peddel')->count(),
        'kortePeddels' => Material::where('type', 'Korte peddel')->count(),
        'tonnetjes' => Material::where('type', 'Tonnetje')->count(),
        'zwemvesten' => Material::where('type', 'Zwemvest')->count()
    );

    return view('materials.index')->with('materials', $materials)->with('stock', $stock)->with('type', $type);
}
```

My code in the view:

```
<section class="pagination">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                {{ $materials->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>
    </div>
</section>
```

A screenshot of my view on small devices:

[image]

Comment: Can you also share how you're displaying the links in the view?

Comment: @apokryfos done so, I've added the code to my original message

Answer (score 7):

First of all The laravel pagination ***onEachSide(x)*** has **leading and tailing parts besides the middle section**. Leading two pages and tailing two pages.

You are trying with ***onEachSide(2)*** and on the 6th page. So now we try to look at the logic in pagination.

In laravel when using ***onEachSide(2)*** it will show pagination like this

| leadingTwoPages | currentPage - 2 | currentPage | currentPage +2 | tailingTwoPages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,2 | 4,5 | 6 | 7,8 | 22,23 |

Then think about the first part of pagination it needs to show the 1st page to the 8th page without the 3rd page.
Instead of page number three, it needs to be a show button with dots.

Then instead of showing a button with dots for page number three, it will show the original 3rd-page number.

*After the 6th page the laravel pagination onEachSide(2) will work fine*

Answer (score 2):

You should use `onEachSide` this in blade.

Remove the `onEachSide` from the controllers. Using `onEachSide` in controllers will be helpful when you are creating APIs. Instead use `onEachSide` in blade file.

```
<section class="pagination">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                {{ $materials->onEachSide(1)->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>
    </div>
</section>
```

Use can manage the link window by changing the parameter in `onEachSide`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#adjusting-the-pagination-link-window

Comment: Yes, I have tried this one, but still with the same result. The pagination is still showing much more items.

Comment: onEachSide(2) remove this from the controller. Only use this in blade.

Comment: @S N Sharma: done so, but with the same result

Comment: @Pieter did you got the answer ?

Comment: @yadusivadas unfortunately no, still don't know what causes this behaviour

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - I think in general it is correct and links to the right resource. Have you tried to apply this answer & also remove the onEachSide call in your controller code? I think it is not meant to use it there.

Comment: @Pieter Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `class="pagination pagination-sm"` for mobile device

Answer (score 2):

It's because of a bug in Laravel 5.* versions. If you don't want to upgrade your app, you should manually change some codes in:

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Pagination/UrlWindow.php

as mentioned and discussed in below link with Taylor Otwell.
[Disccus about on each side bug in Laravel 5.*](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32943)

Comment: Laravel 10 and facing same issue. Not sure its only a Laravel version 5 thing. Though, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 10 here.** (See user- @EHF_Shahab's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401552/3168237))

Thanks to Jehovah's help, What worked for me after searching around is going the manual route.

When calling the `$paginatorVariable->links();` there is the option of pasing it a view.

e.g. `$paginatorVariable->links('thePaginatorView');`

---

For this, create a view in your Laravel project's resource folder:

`MyLaravelProject/resources/views/`

Therefore ending with something like:

`MyLaravelProject/resources/views/thePaginatorView.blade.php`

> > You can see ready made examples in the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Pagination/resources/` folder.
> >
> > The `default.blade.php`, `semantic-ui.blade.php` and `tailwind.blade.php` files are relatively working examples of how to build your view.

The view itself will be "injected" a `$paginator` variable and an `$elements` variable containing each "page element" (page-number and url).

So if you used `$myPaginatorVar->links('myView');`, inside the `myView.blade.php` file, you will have the `$paginator` variable, which will be equal to the `$myPaginatorVar`. And also an `$elements` variable which will be equal to the items array of your paginator variable.

Thus with the `$paginator->currentPage()` function call you can check the page number and compare to the element be it by subtracting to see how far away of the index it is or by plain if-else statements, then skipping or filling up as appropriate.

---

If you don't want to hard-code a fixed amount or if you need to "mimic" the before and after value, you can pass a `['key' => value]` array to the links method call to have such value inside the custom paginator view, as shown [here in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view).

e.g.

```php
$myPaginatorVar->links('myView', ['PagesBeforeAndAfter' => 2]);
```

You could even add multiple different values. For example:

```php
$myPaginatorVar->links('myView', ['showFirstPageWhenNotOnIt' => false,
                                  'pagesAfterFirstPage'      => 0,
                                  'pagesBeforeLastPage'      => 3,
                                  'showLastPageWhenNotOnIt'  => true,
                                  'pagesBeforeAndAfterCurrentPage' => 2]);
```

and use those to compare with the `$paginator->lastPage()`, `$paginator->count()`, `$paginator->currentPage()`, etc... (if you have any amount of pages, you know firstPage is 1).

> *Note: If `$paginator->hasPages()` returns false, no paginator or element will be sensible. That is, there will be no page numbers, previous links, or nextPage links, etc... That is why everything is wrapped up inside an @If checking for `hasPages()` in the 'stock' laravel code in the vendor/laravel/[...]/Paginator/resources folder.

Here are the available functions for using inside the paginator view: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

---

> There is the option of doing this whole same thing to kind of 'override' the default view using the `artisan vendor:publish` command as shown [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view) (or at least that's what I could understand it to be). However I found the regular view way to be more straight forward.